# How to specify filtering data parameters for Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    no2 = models.FloatField()
    co = models.FloatField()
    humidity = models.FloatField()
    temperature = models.FloatField()
```

and rest view:

```
class DataList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.objects.all()
```

I want to have next options to filter data via get parameters (like /entries?period=week):

1. Get last entry
2. Get average values for each of last 7 days
3. Get average values for each of last 12 months.

How to implement it via django rest framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take parameter to your get_queryset method and list your entries according to your parameter.

```
class DataList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        period = request.query_params.get('period')

        if period == 'last': # for last entry
           queryset = Entry.objects.last()
        elif period == 'week': 
            # queryset for week
        elif period == 'month':
            # queryset for month
        return queryset
```

Comment: Just FYI, your initial `if` statement needs to be indented a level.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed You can do this by adjusting `get_queryset` method, but better solution for filtering over api is to use `django-filter` package. DRF support this out of the box :)

```
# filters.py
import django_filters

from rest_framework import filters

class EntryFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    period = django_filters.MethodFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('period', )  # here you can add any fields from Entry model

    def filter_period(self, queryset, value):
        if value == 'last':
            pass
        elif value == 'week':
            pass
        else:
            pass # rest of your if's 
        return queryset
```

Then in your ApiView class

```
class DataList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
    # filtering part
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = EntryFilter
```

Going with this will keep your APIView class clean and more readable and filtering logic is placed where it should be placed.. in filters :)